# Script suddenly stops working but works in other sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Been using getFileById & insertImage in a sheet/program for months with no problem but it suddenly stopped working two days ago.  In order to solve the issue I created a fresh sheet and did this simple code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var picId = "1x2jkgSQvVKAIOg6DQ0rss82YhTQl918c";
  var picToPlace = DriveApp.getFileById(picId);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertImage(picToPlace,1,1);
}
```

It works just like it should however if I stick the same code into my main sheet I get "Exception: The image could not be inserted. Please verify it is valid and try again."

Why is this happening?  I'm not doing anything different, the function is sitting by itself. Been building this sheet/program for months.  Have I overloaded the sheet somehow? Again, if I make a fresh, plain sheet, stick this code in it, it works fine, but if I go back to my main sheet, stick in the same function, it just refuses to work.  Its in its own function, nothing else is happening w/in it, it's the only thing I'm calling.  I'm at a lost trying to figure out why insertImage has completely stopped working in this sheet. There are thousands and thousands lines of code, over 15K rows of data in some tabs, it's referencing hundreds and hundreds of pictures I've uploaded to a server, and processing various aspects of thousands of people I've inputted into this program.  Did I overload this sheet somehow or is Google just over me right now (ie, does it not like me trying to use insertImage, for example, 100 times in one call..)  Sorry, I've put so much effort into this and the "insertImage" function suddenly not working is a major blow to it when it is NOT the code that is malfunctioning.  If it was the code at least I could fix it.

What's odd is I was running the program 2 days ago.  Would look up, for example, 100 people and then have it show me all the pics on one page.  Ran this a few times and in the middle one of the outputs it suddenly stopped working.  I re-ran a query, asked it to show me pictures and it started placing like 20 of them and then just refused to show any more at all.  This really seems like Google telling me to f8ck off.

Comment: Try inserting the same image manually in same sheet! check if it allows you

Comment: If you wish to share some of the code, be glad to take a look at it.

Comment: @Michael It would also be better if you could help the people in this community to be able to replicate your issue & be able to further investigate/to look into what's causing the exception message by providing additional information _(e.g. the sheet, given there's no personal info that shouldn't be shared publicly/code/sample image file to reproduce the issue)_ as described on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is a bit of guesswork, but see if it fixes things for you.
`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` returns a spreadsheet object, not a sheet in the spreadsheet. When you run this code in a fresh spreadsheet, that spreadsheet has a single sheet. And so it works fine. But your main spreadsheet has many sheets. And it breaks down.

Comment: @vector Nope, I'm getting "error occured" when trying to place any image into the sheet manually which is weird because I've inserted countless images into different sheets for years and have never seen this error.

Comment: @IrvinJayG. It's working out of my company's spreadsheet so only those with our email domain can access it.  The insertImage has been working fine for months, was working 2 days ago but after running a few different queries of about 100 people each, and getting it to show me the pictures, it just stopped in the middle of doing it and I hadn't touched one bit of code.

Comment: @Cooper The original function has over 500 lines of codes/comments but even this simplified code isn't working now:

function myFunction() {
 
 var picId = "1x2jkgSQvVKAIOg6DQ0rss82YhTQl918c";
 
 var picToPlace = DriveApp.getFileById(picId);
 
 //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertImage(picToPlace,1,1);
 
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("temp").insertImage(picToPlace,1,1);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("temp").insertImage(picToPlace,1,1);
}

Comment: @ADW I've tried getSheetByName, getActive, getActiveSpreadsheet and combos of those and nothing is happening.   It doesn't seem to be the code but something Google did to make it stop.  Wondering if there's a cache I can empty (if that even is a thing) which might reboot it.

Comment: Well since we can't have access to any of your code and everyone else's guesses have not working how about flushing browsers cache and clearing history.

Comment: It looks that this is not reproducible which makes the question of topic here. Try the Google Apps Script Issue Tracker.

Comment: @Cooper thanks but I gave you an example of code that's not working in the sheet.  I wrote a very simple function to insert an image and it's giving me the same error message.  The problem I'm having is the code was working perfectly for about 3 months, inserting probably close to 1k images until it just stopped which makes me believe it's not the code especially when the most simple insertImage code is giving the same error message.

Comment: @Rubén Thanks - I just went back and reverted to the last saved copy I had of my program from a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same exact issue. I suspect you are right when you said, "This really seems like Google telling me to f8ck off."

Once this happens, it seems like it is permanent (not some timeout ban you can wait out).  However, I found it to be document ID related - so if you make a copy of the sheet (or possibly revert, as you did - though I am not sure if the document id changes in that case - and if it doesn't, then that throws my diagnosis out...) - anything which changes that document id to a new one - the insertImage calls will work again.

Below is another related thread about it where I posted more about my experience.

[Google sheet insertImage function stopped working for Google Apps Script: verify image error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66229086/google-sheet-insertimage-function-stopped-working-for-google-apps-script-verify/)

If google doesn't want us using this function the way we are, they damn well should tell us about it in the documentation for insertImage!